# small line x-axis for years

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have data covering a time period of over 25 years. In the data set are over 6300 days. I would like to show the years on the x-axix.

```
dates <- as.Date(DOL[,1], "%d.%m.%Y")
DOL <- as.xts(DOL[,2], dates)

plot(DOL, xaxt = "n", main="SMA", ann = FALSE)
axis(1, at=as.POSIXct(dates),labels=format(dates,"%Y"),tick=TRUE)
title(ylab = "Value")
title(xlab = "Time")
```

the  graph looks like this:

[image]

I would like to have single lines at the x axis for each year instead of the black big  bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I see what you mean.

One way to handle this would be to create two time series, and use one for your calculations and plotting your data, and the other for the tic marks. Like this:

```
library(xts)
n <- 1000
d1 <- seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"),as.Date("2021-01-01"),length.out=n)
d1y <- seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"),as.Date("2021-01-01"),length.out=21)
d2 <- rnorm(n,10,1)
Dollar <- data.frame(d1,d2)
dates <- as.Date(Dollar[,1], "%d.%m.%Y",tz="GMT") 
xtsplot <- as.xts(Dollar[,2], dates)
plot(xtsplot, xaxt = "n", main="SMA", ann = FALSE)
axis(1, at=as.POSIXct(d1y),labels=format(d1y,"%Y"))
title(ylab = "Value")
title(xlab = "Time")
```

There could be other ways too...

[image]